# Which one is better? Conversion and Type Cast

Tags: c#

I would like to know which way is better and faster for the following scenarios.

```
string dateStart = ((DateTime)dtRow["StartDate"]).ToShortDateString();
```

or

```
string dateStart = DateTime.Parse(dtRow["StartDate"].ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: [Must read](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: What did your measurements show? Is this the bottleneck of your application?

Comment: If you know `dtRow["StartDate"]` is a `DateTime`, why convert it to and from and then **again** to a string? I'd do **1)** simply because **2)** is awful.

Comment: See the link @AustinSalonen just posted for the answer to "performance". For "Better", it depends on what "Better" means for you. You can actually get different functional results from those two lines of code. Simply casting the value from your DataTable may actually not work when a Parse does work, if the value is a string that is of a strange format. Parse is more "flexible" than casting is, in some cases.

Comment: @AustinSalonen: Second is inappropriate regardless performance rant.

Comment: @abatishchev The second is very appropriate if this is a string in some different format than what he wants it in.

Comment: @abatishchev:  The link is still a must read to prevent future poor questions.

Comment: @Jaxidian: Underlying data is DateTime otherwise first will throw exception. If question takes place then it doesn't throw then underlying data is DateTime indeed.

Comment: @abatishchev No, underlying data could simply be `object` and both could conditionally work. But I understand your point, and ultimately, we'd argue the same thing here - don't cast if it's a datetime, and don't store datetimes in any other format.

Comment: @Jaxidian: How would you keep data to represent it as object? As `sql_variant`? I bet it is not. And also it will not be "simply" but much harder :) In theory you're right, I agree, but in this particular case - most probably it's just twice-converter DateTime.

Comment: @abatishchev I agree, most likely. Silly things we argue about... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If the type of value stored in the `StartDate` column of data-table is already `DateTime`, the first one is faster than the second. Otherwise we can't compare them, because the first one crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Cast is doubtfully better because is only appropriate way if underlying data is type of DateTime or compatible.

Second way converts DateTime to String and then back to DateTime what is pointless.